# How can I avoid page scrolling up on clicking a simple link (#)

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to avoid scrolling page up on clicking a simple link such as the one given below:

```
<a href="#">Click Me</a>
```

Comment: Why's it even a link in the first place?

Comment: For some JQuery purpose.

Comment: Why not just make it a `span` with `cursor: pointer;`?

Comment: You can also trigger jQuery events with class or id.

Comment: The given code is just a sample. A simple use case. I just wanted to know if there's a way to avoid page scrolling when I use the link as `#`.

Comment: [**Links are not buttons**](http://www.karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans/**).

Comment: ^ Thanks for the article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following one:

```
<a href="#!"> Click Me </a>
```

Comment: Links like this will still change the page URL, resulting in an extra entry in the browser's history and causing the "back" button to simply remove the fragment from the URL instead of doing what the user expects.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

**HTML**

```
<div>Test</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Click me</a>
```

**CSS**

```
div{
   height: 1000px;
}
```

The `div` is only for demonstration.
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkurzweil/1m6z1ejd/)

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent the default action in a JavaScript event handler with [Event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) like this:

```
$('#link').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

(Assuming the link has the id `link` You said you use jQuery, so I used jQuery syntax here)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r6w87pzk/)